# Какое сказуемое в предложении

Tags: сказуемые, подлежащее

Рассмотрим два одинаковых по смыслу и "грамматике" предложения:

> Мне нравится есть помидоры.

> Есть помидоры — мне нравится.

Какие сказуемые в этих предложениях? Почему в одинаковых по смыслу и "грамматике" предложениях разные сказуемые?

Comment: @190920 - *Почему в одинаковых по смыслу и грамматике предложениях, разные сказуемые?* - Ась? Если сказуемые разные, то грамматика разная, нет?

Comment: Давайте отвечать на вопросы последовательно. Вы не ответили на первый вопрос. Тогда второй может и не понадобиться

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для дискуссий.  Ни на какой второй вопрос я не отвечал. Я вам просто показал абсурдность вашей логики.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А почему разные? В обоих случаях сказуемое составное глагольное ***нравится есть***, просто в первом предложении прямой порядок слов, конструкция правильная литературная, а второе предложение - разговорная конструкция, с инверсией и интонационным тире.

У Розенталя § 7. Интонационное тире:

> 1. Тире ставится для указания места разделения простого предложения на словесные группы, чтобы подчеркнуть либо уточнить смысловые отношения
>    между членами предложения, когда другими знаками препинания или
>    порядком слов нужный смысл не может быть выражен. Ср.:
>
> Ходить — долго не мог (‘лишен был возможности передвигаться в течение
> длительного периода, например после тяжелой болезни’); Ходить долго —
> не мог (‘не мог заниматься длительной ходьбой’);
>
> В случае нужды — прошу (‘в случае нужды прошу обратиться ко мне’); В
> случае нужды прошу (‘обращаюсь с просьбой, когда испытываю нужду’).
>
> Такое тире, называемое интонационным, может отделять любую часть
> предложения:
> Пошли в клуб — почитать, поиграть в шашки, потанцевать — тире перед
> однородными обстоятельствами цели подчеркивает их связь со сказуемым
> (ср. также: Беру бинокль — наблюдать)

Так что здесь только смысл разный:

*Мне нравится есть помидоры*. Нейтральное заявление о том, что автору нравится процесс поедания помидоров.

*Есть помидоры — мне нравится.* Акцент на психическом переживании: ему именно нравится этот процесс, а не что-то другое - не восторгается им, не ненавидит, не любит, не боится.

Другая грамматика (другое сказуемое) было бы  в примере с **составным именным** сказуемым, там инверсия играет большую роль при различении типа предложений: *Приятно есть помидоры* - безличное, сказуемое ***приятно есть***. *Есть помидоры - это приятно* - двусоставное, есть - подлежащее, **приятно - сказуемое**.

Comment: Супер! Без иронии: так не хватало четких объяснений уровня 8 класса.
А что насчет https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/463340
?

Comment: @Людмила а как насчет самой постановки вопроса? *Почему в одинаковых по смыслу и "грамматике" предложениях разные сказуемые?* - вы вообще можете себе представить предложения с типологически разными сказуемыми, но одинаковой "грамматикой"? )))) На мой взляд, автор так и не понял ничего...

Comment: @Людмила если что "грамматика" в своем вопросе я написал в кавычках)))) А  уважаемый behemothus на мой взгляд плавает в теме, ведь он молчаливо согласился с предыдущим неправильным ответом.

Answer (score 1):

1. нравится есть
2. нравится

В первом акцент на ощущении от действия, безличное предложение. Во втором идет рассуждение о "есть помидоры" - и об этом говорится, что нравится. Вот оно, богатство языка! Это вроде об одном, но все же очень по-разному.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118983/discussion-on-answer-by-nadezhda----).